# Codeblocks 20.03 isn't compiling

Tags: 21.04

I have installed Codeblocks 20.03 successfully in ubuntu 21.04. Even I coded right but the code is not running successfully. So what can I do for it?

Comment: "coded right but the code is not running successfuly" contains two unexplained assertions, and no actual information.

Answer (score 0):

So your installation of Codeblocks is not full. It is [packaged](https://packages.ubuntu.com/hirsute/codeblocks) in *universe* repository pocket.

For correct installation you have to install it as follows:

```
sudo apt-add-repository universe
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install codeblocks
```

and then install compilers by

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential # for GCC
sudo apt-get install gfortran llvm clang # optional
```

then create a simple project using *File* → *New Project* wizard and compile it.